# memcpy -- copying uint64 to char *

Tags: c++, c

I just don't know what memcpy works. You can simply copy paste the code and see how the output doesn't add up. I know I can write the code in some other ways but I just wonder why memcpy does not work.

```
typedef unsigned char* bitmap;
#define getbit(n,bmp) ((bmp[(n)>>3])&(0x80>>((n)&0x07)))
#define setbit(n,bmp) {bmp[(n)>>3]|=(0x80>>((n)&0x07));}
#define bitmapsize(n) (((int)(n)+7)>>3)
#define to_uint64(buffer,n) ((uint64_t)buffer[n] << 56 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+1] << 48 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+2] << 40  | (uint64_t)buffer[n+3] << 32 | (uint64_t) buffer[n+4] << 24 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+5] << 16 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+6] << 8  | (uint64_t)buffer[n+7])

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bitmap bm1, bm2,bm3;
    unsigned int m_size=128;

    if (!(bm1 = (bitmap) calloc (bitmapsize(m_size), sizeof(char))));             
    setbit(100,bm1);     

    if (!(bm2 = (bitmap) calloc (bitmapsize(m_size), sizeof(char))));
    setbit(120,bm2);     

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bitmapsize(m_size)/sizeof(uint64_t); i++)
    {
            uint64_t or_res = (to_uint64(bm2, i * sizeof(uint64_t))) | (to_uint64(bm1, i * sizeof(uint64_t)));
            std::cout<<std::bitset<64>(or_res)<<" ";
            memcpy(bm1 + i * sizeof(uint64_t), &or_res, sizeof(uint64_t));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<m_size;i++)
            if (getbit(i,bm1))   std::cout<<i<<"  ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    free(bm1);
    free(bm2);
    return 0;
 }
```

the output:
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000

64  92

The numbers should be simply 100 120 but they are not!

Comment: memcpy works just fine ... !!!!!!! :-O

Comment: Can you extract the part that's giving you trouble from that large piece of code, and describe exactly what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: lol... it doesn't... it took me so far 3 hours... I don't know what is wrong (I am sure it is something so stupid... but I do not know what is wrong)

Comment: Okay, sorry for the jokes, I think I might see what's going on ... answer to follow ...

Comment: I have get rid of all unnecessary things, so you can see the main code more clearly...it is so frustrating!

Comment: I'm guessing this is a 2's compliment error since I don't see every use of integers cast to unsigned.  Esp. in the macros.

Comment: hmm... i didn't get it... what would be your suggestion to solve it?

Comment: looking at bitset results... it seems the code is correct.. right? you can easily test getbit and setbit as well... I am using them for a while, so I am sure they should be alright as well...

Comment: well I put this for (int i=0; i<m_size;i++) if (getbit(i,bm1))   std::cout<<i<<"  "; right after than set bit and it returns me 100. So  I guess it is correct.

Comment: Okay, sorry again, I didn't see a value in your array (lots of zeroes in `gdb` with only two "eights" is easy to miss :) ... the 13th byte of `bm1` is set to 0x8 and the 15th byte of `bm2` is set to 0x80.  So it does seem your `setbit()` code is working right, or at least is setting the correct intended values, if that's what you were intending.

Comment: Stepping through the code some more, `memcpy` is working.  Since everything else is all 0x0 except for the second 64-bit word of `bm1` and `bm2` when `i == 1` ... after that OR operation, the value of `or_res` is `134217856` or `0x8000080` ... that value ends up in the second 64-bit word of `bm1` after the `memcpy` call just like you instructed the code to-do ... so there's nothing wrong with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are having an issue with endianness.  When you cast your buffer to a `uint64_t` you are casting your buffer into a little endian `uint64_t`. So your bytes would then be ordered as follows:

ie.

```
buffer:   | char 0 | char 1 | char 2 | ... | char n
uint64_t: | byte 8 | byte 7 | byte 6 | ... | byte 0
```

You are then copying this uint64_t directly into you buffer so your bytes are being ordered incorrectly.

The easiest fix is to change your `to_uint64` macro:

```
#define to_uint64(buffer,n) ((uint64_t)buffer[n+7] << 56 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+6] << 48 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+5] << 40  | (uint64_t)buffer[n+4] << 32 | (uint64_t) buffer[n+3] << 24 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+2] << 16 | (uint64_t)buffer[n+1] << 8  | (uint64_t)buffer[n])
```

However, this will give you issues if you try and use your code on a big endian machine.

Actually, a better method would be to use:

```
#define to_uint64(buffer,n) (*(uint64_t*)(buffer + n))
```

Edit: I changed the macro above, as caf pointed out I don't need to case a `uint64_t` to a `uint64_t`.  The way the macro works is that it casts the buffer pointer (`unsinged char *`) to a `uint64_t` pointer and then dereferences it.

Comment: wow... That macro looks much cooler... it is much nicer that ugly macro... :-) Yet I am trying to understand how it works...

Comment: Why are you casting a `uint64_t` value to `uint64_t`?

Comment: @caf: Oh you are right, I don't know why I left that there :)